# Can I set the class instance when calling the method?

Tags: c++, class

If I have a class `myClass`, and I have two instances of it, `class1` and `class2`, but then set which instance I want to use at which time, would I be able to?

So for example:

```
if (whichClass == 1) {
    class1.result();
} else if (whichClass == 2) {
    class2.result();
}
```

Is a way I could do it, but I'd like to avoid the if statement so I would like to do something along the lines of

```
string whichClass = "class1";    //global
```

And then somewhere else...

```
whichClass.result();             //this depends on what whichClass is at any particular time.
```

where the `whichClass` variable was changing on its own, for example in another thread, every 60 seconds.

Comment: Perhaps a suitable [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) object bound by [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) or using a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) which calls the function in the correct object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this with a string, but it's precisely what a pointer could do:

```
myClass *whichClass = &class1;

whichClass->result();
```

If you intend to access `whichClass` from more than one thread, though, you will have to synchronise access to it. You can either do this by protecting it through a mutex, or by making it atomic. Here's an example of the latter:

```
std::atomic<myClass*> whichClass{&class1};

whichClass = &class2;

whichClass.load()->result();
```

Note that this only protects the pointer itself (i.e. it's safe to set it in one thread and dereference it in another). The object to which it points is not protected (i.e. it's not in general safe to call `result` through it in more than one thread).

Answer (score 1):

Use a pointer:

```cpp
myClass *whichObj;

if (whichClass == 1) {
    whichObj = &class1;
}
else if (whichClass == 2) {
    whichObj = &class2;
}
...
which->result();
```

If you really want to get rid of the `if`s, use an array:

```cpp
myClass* clsObjs[] = {
    &class1,
    &class2
    ...
};

clsObjs[whichClass-1]->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

The initial question didn't specify that class1 and class2 were derived from a common base class. So I disagree with the previous answers. There is no need to tighten these two classes, and I think it's better to let them loosely coupled as much as it can be.

I think a better approach is to use function overloading:

```
class class1 {...} ;
class class2 {...} ;

void result(const class1 & c)
{
  // do what is needed with class1
}

void result(const class2 & c)
{
  // do what is needed with class2
}

int main()
{
  class1 c1 ;
  class2 c2 ;
  result(c1) ;
  result(c2) ;
  return 0 ;
}
```

There is no `if` at all, and you let the compiler do all the checks for you. So there is no chance to make a mistake between the condition of the test and the body to execute.

Comment: "I have a class myClass, and I have two instances of it, class1 and class2". `class1` and `class2` are objects of ONE type, `myClass`.

Comment: OK I understand. I thought it was instances of two different classes. If I were you, I would have written instance1 and instance2 for clarity. My answer is not the one you were looking after.

Comment: I am not the asker, I was just clarifying.